# What is a nice way to have named pre-defined structs?

Tags: c++, struct

Given the following example:

```cpp
#pragma once

#include <cstdint>

namespace Color
{

    struct RGBColor
    {
        uint8_t red;
        uint8_t green;
        uint8_t blue;
    };

    RGBColor Red{ 255, 0, 0 };
    // More colors

};
```

So I can have something like this:

```cpp
RGBColor color = Color::Red;
```

But having `Color::Red` defined like this probably isn't the nicest way to do this.
Is there a better way?

Edit:
Forgot to mention that I got a `variable definition in header file` error, but using `const/constexpr` seems to be the solution for that.

Comment: `Color::Red` is exactly what I would do, perhaps `Color::RBGColor::Red`. Anyhow, this quesiton is purely opinion based

Comment: `constexpr RGBColor Red{ 255, 0, 0 };` without `constexpr` or `const` you will have linking issues (duplicated symbol), since it is header file.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Having the definition of the constants in the header file will cause you a multiple definition error if you include the header file in multiple translation units.  In ye olden times you had to declare the variables with the `extern` keyword and then define the variables in a single cpp file.  With modern C++ we can use `inline` on the variables instead and just have the definition in the header file like

```
#pragma once

#include <cstdint>

namespace Color
{

    struct RGBColor
    {
        std::uint8_t red;
        std::uint8_t green;
        std::uint8_t blue;
    };

    inline RGBColor Red{ 255, 0, 0 };
    // More colors

};
```

If you want these to be constants, then you should include `constexpr` like

```
inline constexpr RGBColor Red{ 255, 0, 0 };
// More colors
```

Comment: If you're thinking, "Ah ha! `#pragma once` prevents this!" remember that `once` prevents multiple inclusions in one run of the compiler. If you are compiling multiple files, each is a separate pass through the compiler, and *every* file including this header will include the header exactly once. [When the linker puts the compiler output together](https://stackoverflow.com/q/6264249/4581301), it will find the duplicate identifiers unless extra steps like `inline` are taken.

Comment: @user4581301 -- not to mention that `#pragma once` is non-standard and in some environments unimplementable.